# Nginx custom 403 page not working

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

Trying to add a custom page for my website, but for whatever reason, no matter what I change it to, it doesn't work. Whenever I change the 404, it works fine.

```
error_page 403 /blocked.php;
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 /500.html;
error_page 502 /502.html;
error_page 503 /503.html;
error_page 504 /504.html;
```

The 403 page always returns the default nginx page regardless of what I change it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

Before "error_page" directives:
This directive allows nginx to recognize the error code being returned from Apache and run its own directives to display the right page.

Comment: Old question, old answer, but this worked for me. It was the only way to get 403 error_page handling to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
error_page 403 = /blocked.php;
```

Here's [the reference](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)